# How to change the color and width of the shapefiles via arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I have many Shapefiles in the same folder. Each shapefile contains polylines. I want to change the color and width of the lines. I'm quite new to ArcGIS and hope someone can help me.

> ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (in_layer, in_symbology_layer)

Is this what I have to use? How to generate an "in_symbology_layer"?

The following code is what I have so far and I will edit it if I know any information.

```
import glob, os
import arcpy

the_path = r"C:/project/"
os.chdir(the_path)

for file in glob.glob("*.shp"):

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]

    newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(the_path+file)

    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newlayer,"TOP")

    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()

    del mxd, df, newlayer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management. You first need to [create a layer file](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/saving-layers-and-layer-packages.htm) with the symbology you need, then apply the symbology to the layer.

```
....
newlayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(the_path+file)

# Set layer that output symbology will be based on
symbologyLayer = "water_symbols_pnt.lyr"

# Apply the symbology from the symbology layer to the input layer
arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management (newlayer, symbologyLayer)
```

Comment: Could you give me more detail about the symbology layer? What thing I have to put on this layer. Is the blank layer?

Comment: **It's in the link**. Manually add data to ArcMap, click on the layer symbol to change it. Right-click the layer name and click Save as Layer File. Use the layer file in script.